# Fill in missing values for joined tables in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery which contains net stock quantity for every day when some transaction occurs and table with price history, something like this:

```
WITH `trans` AS (
SELECT DATE '2018-10-02' trans_date, 10.0 quantity UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-03', 5.0 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-05', 11.0 
),
`prices` AS (
SELECT DATE '2018-10-01' price_date, 1.0 price UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-02', 2.0 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-03', 3.0 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-04', 4.0 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-05', 5.0 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-06', 6.0 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-07', 7.0 
)
SELECT 
price_date,
quantity, 
price
FROM (
SELECT price_date, quantity, price, trans_date FROM `trans`
RIGHT JOIN `prices`
ON trans.trans_date = prices.price_date
ORDER BY price_date
)
```

And I can't figure out how to fill in last known quantity where there is no transaction for that date, to get result something like this:

```
price_date    quantity  price
2018-10-01    0.0    1.0
2018-10-02    10.0   2.0
2018-10-03    5.0    3.0
2018-10-04    5.0    4.0
2018-10-05    11.0   5.0
2018-10-06    11.0   6.0
2018-10-07    11.0   7.0
```

next step would be then to calculate value over time.
I will be grateful for any example / suggestion how to do it.

EDIT:
I added stock symbols, to match more real example

```
WITH `trans` AS (
SELECT DATE '2018-10-02' trans_date, 10.0 quantity, 'TX' symbol UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-03' trans_date, 5.0 quantity, 'TX' UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-05', 11.0, 'AX' 
),
`prices` AS (
 SELECT DATE '2018-10-01' price_date, 1.0 price, 'TX' symbol UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-02', 2.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-03', 3.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-04', 4.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-05', 5.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-06', 6.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-07', 7.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-08', 8.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-09', 9.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-10', 10.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-11', 11.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-12', 12.0, 'TX' 
)

SELECT
  price_date, 
  t.symbol AS symbol,
  IFNULL(
    ARRAY_AGG(
      IF(p.price_date >= t.trans_date AND p.symbol = t.symbol, quantity, NULL) 
      IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY trans_date DESC LIMIT 1
      )[OFFSET(0)],
  -1234567890) quantity,
  price
FROM `prices` p
CROSS JOIN `trans` t
GROUP BY price_date, price, symbol
HAVING quantity != -1234567890
ORDER BY price_date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `trans` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-02' trans_date, 10.0 quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-03', 5.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-05', 11.0 
),
`prices` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-01' price_date, 1.0 price UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-02', 2.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-03', 3.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-04', 4.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-05', 5.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-06', 6.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-07', 7.0 
)
SELECT 
  price_date, 
  IFNULL(
    ARRAY_AGG(
      IF(p.price_date >= t.trans_date, quantity, NULL) 
      IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY trans_date DESC LIMIT 1
      )[OFFSET(0)],
  0) quantity,
  price
FROM `prices` p
CROSS JOIN `trans` t
GROUP BY price_date, price
-- ORDER BY price_date
```

Comment: thanks. I was going in this direction initially. When I replace in WITH clauses selects from tables, I get this error from BQ validator: "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN."

Comment: sorry - my bad. didn't have chance to test. try updated version

Comment: I was just wandering if this can't be improved to be more efficient, in reality both tables have also "stock symbol" column and prices table has ~900k rows and transactions has ~1M (and more) rows. Whole query takes ~18 minutes, I'm doing some other things beside this JOIN, but it looks like it takes the most significant part of query time. Output of join is 131G rows which is further aggregated and filtered to 14M rows. In description I added query which reflects more realistically how I'm doing it.

Comment: 1. you cannot avoid JOIN here. 2. from what I understand - your initial/original question is answered, so I would suggest to post new question - if you do - make sure the title is quite different and reflect he new issue you have - otherwise it will be closed as a duplicate

Comment: Indeed the CROSS JOIN is very inefficient. The ARRAY_AGG method in Gordon Linoff's answer should be selected as the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
select p.price_date,
       coalesce(t.quantity, lag(t.quantity ignore nulls) over (order by p.price_date)) as quantity
       p.price
from prices p join
     trans t
     on t.trans_date = p.price_date;
```

EDIT:

That's right.  `IGNORE NULL`s works in some contexts but not others.  Arrays are usually the fix in BigQuery:

```
select price_date,
       (select quantity
        from unnest(quantities) quantity with OFFSET n
        where quantity is not null
        order by n desc
        LIMIT 1
       ) as quantity,
       price
from (select p.price_date,
             array_agg(t.quantity) over (order by p.price_date) as quantities,
             p.price
      from prices p LEFT join
           trans t
           on t.trans_date = p.price_date
    ) pp;
```

Comment: BigQuery validator says IGNORE NULLS and RESPECT NULLS are not allowed for analytic function LAG

Comment: it looks like this could work. when I remove "ignore nulls" I get almost desired results, I would just need to handle first and last row since they are null. thanks

Comment: thanks. unfortunately as per documentation for ARRAY_AGG when using OVER is "incompatible" with IGNORE NULLS   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg

Comment: One workaround I found is using default value for nulls in ARRAY_AGG, i.e. ARRAY_AGG(IFNULL(t.quantity, -1)...) and then filter out those values in next select ARRAY(SELECT x FROM UNNEST(quantities) AS x WHERE x != -1) AS quantities,

Comment: @zdenulo . . . You don't need to use a special value.  This time, I tested the specific code.  It did not occur to me that `ARRAY_AGG()`would not accept `IGNORE NULL`s with an `ORDER BY`; I often use `IGNORE NULL`s with `ARRAY_AGG()`.