# BigQuery: Extra rows when doing cross join and adding another field to be partitioned

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Question is somewhat related to my previous [Fill in missing values for joined tables in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648489/fill-in-missing-values-for-joined-tables-in-bigquery).

Basically I have 2 tables. One with stock transactions other with stock prices. Goal is to have table where for every day for which there is price, value is calculated. This was answered in previous question. (Doing CROSS JOIN and ARRAY_AGG to fill in missing amount for date where stock price exists, but there wasn't any transaction).

Now if I want to add other values like "running amount / balance" then result is broken, basically every row is doubled (date and stock symbol) since I am adding other field (running_amount) to by partitioned (which I have to do). Here my understanding of SQL ends :) so I would appreciate any help or suggestion. Goal is to have one line per date and stock symbol.

Here is full sample query:

```
WITH `trans` AS (
SELECT DATE '2018-10-02' trans_date, 10.0 stock_amount, 'TX' stock_symbol UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-03', 5.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-05', 11.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-10-10', 10.0, 'AX' 

),
`prices` AS (
 SELECT DATE '2018-10-01' price_date, 1.0 price, 'TX' symbol UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-02', 2.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-03', 3.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-04', 4.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-05', 5.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-06', 6.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-07', 7.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-08', 8.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-08', 8.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-09', 9.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-09', 9.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-10', 10.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-10', 10.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-11', 11.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-11', 11.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-12', 11.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-12', 12.0, 'TX' 
)

SELECT
  price_date, 
  tx.stock_symbol AS token_symbol,
  IFNULL(
    ARRAY_AGG(
      IF(p.price_date >= tx.trans_date AND p.symbol = tx.stock_symbol, stock_amount, NULL) 
      IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY trans_date DESC LIMIT 1
      )[OFFSET(0)],
  -1234567890) stock_amount,
  running_amount,    
  price

FROM (
   SELECT
       trans_date,
       stock_symbol,
       stock_amount,
       SUM(stock_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY stock_symbol ORDER BY trans_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_amount
   FROM `trans`
   ORDER BY stock_symbol, trans_date
)
AS tx
CROSS JOIN `prices` as p
GROUP BY price_date, price, token_symbol
,running_amount
HAVING stock_amount != -1234567890
ORDER BY stock_symbol, price_date
```

This result is expected:

```
Row price_date  token_symbol    stock_amount    running_amount  price
1   2018-10-08  AX  11  11  8
2   2018-10-09  AX  11  11  9
3   2018-10-10  AX  10  21  10
4   2018-10-11  AX  10  21  11
5   2018-10-12  AX  10  21  11
6   2018-10-02  TX  10  10  2
7   2018-10-03  TX  5   15  3
8   2018-10-04  TX  5   15  4
9   2018-10-05  TX  5   15  5
10  2018-10-06  TX  5   15  6
11  2018-10-07  TX  5   15  7
12  2018-10-08  TX  5   15  8
13  2018-10-09  TX  5   15  9
14  2018-10-10  TX  5   15  10
15  2018-10-11  TX  5   15  11
16  2018-10-12  TX  5   15  12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `trans` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-02' trans_date, 10.0 stock_amount, 'TX' stock_symbol UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-03', 5.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-05', 11.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-10', 10.0, 'AX' 

), `prices` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-01' price_date, 1.0 price, 'TX' symbol UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-02', 2.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-03', 3.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-04', 4.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-05', 5.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-06', 6.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-07', 7.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-08', 8.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-08', 8.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-09', 9.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-09', 9.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-10', 10.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-10', 10.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-11', 11.0, 'TX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-11', 11.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-12', 11.0, 'AX' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-10-12', 12.0, 'TX' 
)
SELECT
  price_date, 
  tx.stock_symbol AS token_symbol,
  IFNULL(
    ARRAY_AGG(
      IF(p.price_date >= tx.trans_date AND p.symbol = tx.stock_symbol, stock_amount, NULL) 
      IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY trans_date DESC LIMIT 1
      )[OFFSET(0)],
  -1234567890) stock_amount,
  SUM(
    IF(p.price_date >= tx.trans_date AND p.symbol = tx.stock_symbol, stock_amount, 0) 
  ) running_amount,
  price
FROM `trans` AS tx
CROSS JOIN `prices` AS p
WHERE stock_symbol = symbol
GROUP BY price_date, price, token_symbol
HAVING stock_amount != -1234567890
-- ORDER BY stock_symbol, price_date
```

with result

```
Row price_date  token_symbol    stock_amount    running_amount  price    
1   2018-10-08  AX              11.0            11.0            8.0  
2   2018-10-09  AX              11.0            11.0            9.0  
3   2018-10-10  AX              10.0            21.0            10.0     
4   2018-10-11  AX              10.0            21.0            11.0     
5   2018-10-12  AX              10.0            21.0            11.0     
6   2018-10-02  TX              10.0            10.0            2.0  
7   2018-10-03  TX              5.0             15.0            3.0  
8   2018-10-04  TX              5.0             15.0            4.0  
9   2018-10-05  TX              5.0             15.0            5.0  
10  2018-10-06  TX              5.0             15.0            6.0  
11  2018-10-07  TX              5.0             15.0            7.0  
12  2018-10-08  TX              5.0             15.0            8.0  
13  2018-10-09  TX              5.0             15.0            9.0  
14  2018-10-10  TX              5.0             15.0            10.0     
15  2018-10-11  TX              5.0             15.0            11.0     
16  2018-10-12  TX              5.0             15.0            12.0
```

Comment: Thanks for response Mikhail. I wasn't concrete enough. running_amount should be changed for transaction days only, for days in between it should be the same, that's why I was doing it in transaction sub select. With your query it adds for every date, which is not what I need. I hope it's clearer now

Comment: I will check again when get some time :o)

Comment: looks like my updated answer gives you exactly what you expected :o)